# Pausing while loop until button has been pressed?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating a blackjack app for a school project and I'm trying to create a function that makes it possible if the ace card is worth 1 or 11, this is what I have so far:

```
fun drawCard(amount: Int) {
        var loopedTimes: Int = 0

        while(loopedTimes != amount) {
            val rand = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
            val randomValue = rand.nextInt(12)

            cardsArray[loopedTimes].setImageResource(allCards[randomValue].cardImage)
            myScore += allCards[randomValue].cardValue

            if(allCards[randomValue].cardName == "Ace") {
                val aceOneButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.aceOneButton)
                val aceElevenButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.aceElevenButton)

                aceOneButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                aceElevenButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                aceOneButton.setOnClickListener {
                    myScore -= 10 // Sänk värdet med 10
                }
            }

            loopedTimes++
            playerCurrentCard++
            myScoreText.text = myScore.toString()
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the while loop doesn't wait until the player has pressed the ace button, is there any way to make loop wait for the button to get pressed?

Comment: what is the value of `amount`?

Comment: The way buttons work is you react to them, not wait for them. You react by adding click listeners. So you can’t have a function that runs through your logic sequentially and waits for a button press and then does something else. You’ll need to think in terms of keeping the current status of the game in a variable and having the button call a function that decides each time it is called what to do next based on the current status of the game.

Comment: Or you could write a different function for each stage of your game, and at the end of each function, it sets a new click listener on the button that calls the function for the next stage of the game. Or an alternate solution would be to use a coroutine that does work similarly to your code above, but calls `receive()` on a Channel that the button calls `send()` on when clicked. But coroutines are an advanced topic, not for beginners.